# Convert string list to string when only item present

Tags: c#, string

I have a function that returns a list of strings:

```
string displayText;
List<string> list = new List<string>();
list = GetListOfStrings();
if(list.Count > 1)
{
    displayText = string.Join("\r", list.ToArray());
}
else
{
    displayText = list.ToString();
}
```

If there are several string in the List then I separate them by \r for display purposes, if there is only one then I cant to convert it to string.

But the above shows **"System.Collections.Generic.List1[System.String]"** when there is only one string.

What is the best way to do this when there is only one string in the list?

Comment: Just use `string.Join("\r", list)` it will handle the case when the list contains only one item

Comment: `var displayText = string.Join("\r", GetListOfStrings());` - 11 lines down to 1, and more efficient

Comment: ToString() method is not overriden for List<T>, so by using `list.ToString()` you will get object.ToString() implementation which, as you could see, returns the fullname of the type.

Answer (score 2):

No reason to use `ToString` on the list -- just grab the first (and only) item:

```
displayText = list[0];
```

Both answers in the comments seem correct as well, though `ToString` on a `string` is a bit redundant. I think "remove the if" is actually the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use **SingleOrDefault()** for getting the only item in the list

```
if(list.Count > 1)
{
    displayText = string.Join("\r", list.ToArray());
}
else
{
    displayText = list.SingleOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: add namespace System.Linq

Comment: Sure you don't mean `FirstOrDefault`?

Comment: FirstOrDefault returns the first element of the list. It can also be used in this case. But for returning a single item SingleOrDefault() is used. Both can work fine

Answer (score 0):

Not having more than one item doesn't mean it has one item.
You can use:

```
string displayText;
List<string> list = new List<string>();
list = GetListOfStrings();
displayText = string.Join("\r", list);
```

Comment: (need  to  assign `displayText`, no need for the `new List<string>()`, and no need  for the `ToArray()`)